# Connect MySQL database in Kotlin Using mysql-connector is Not working

Tags: android, mysql, kotlin, jdbc

Currently, I am trying to connect MySql Db using   `implementation("com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.2.0")` but I am getting an error it is perfectly connected in the Command line but in Android app is not working I don't what is the problem with my code.

```
class DispenserDatabaseHelper(context: Context?) {


    private  val DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://sql.freedb.tech:3306/freedb_dispenser_data"
    private var conn: Connection? = null
    private var username = "freedb_tobeitsolutions"
    private var password = "ayJ?DpgEMp57WBV"

    fun executeMySQLQuery() {
        var stmt: Statement? = null
        var resultset: ResultSet? = null
        try {
            stmt = conn!!.createStatement()
            resultset = stmt!!.executeQuery("SHOW DATABASES;")
            if (stmt.execute("SHOW DATABASES;")) {
                resultset = stmt.resultSet
            }
            while (resultset!!.next()) {
                println(resultset.getString("Database"))
            }
        } catch (ex: SQLException) {
            // handle any errors
            ex.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            // release resources
            if (resultset != null) {
                try {
                    resultset.close()
                } catch (sqlEx: SQLException) {
                }
                resultset = null
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                try {
                    stmt.close()
                } catch (sqlEx: SQLException) {
                }
                stmt = null
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn!!.close()
                } catch (sqlEx: SQLException) {
                }
                conn = null
            }
        }
    }

    fun getConnection() {
        val connectionProps = Properties()
        connectionProps.put("user", username)
        connectionProps.put("password", password)
        try {
            //Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:" + "mysql" + "://" +
                        "sql.freedb.tech" +
                        ":" + "3306" + "/" +
                        "",
                connectionProps)
        } catch (ex: SQLException) {
            // handle any errors
            ex.printStackTrace()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            // handle any errors
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

here is error details

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
15:32:17.012  W     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:111)
15:32:17.012  W     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:98)
15:32:17.012  W     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:90)
15:32:17.012  W     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:64)
15:32:17.012  W     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:991)
15:32:17.012  W     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:805)
15:32:17.012  W     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:438)
15:32:17.012  W     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
15:32:17.012  W     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:189)
15:32:17.013  W     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
15:32:17.013  W     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
15:32:17.013  W     at DispenserDatabaseHelper.getConnection(DispenserDatabaseHelper.kt:64)
15:32:17.013  W     at com.app.bemvindo.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.kt:63)
15:32:17.013  W     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
15:32:17.013  W     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
15:32:17.013  W     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
15:32:17.013  W     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
15:32:17.013  W     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
15:32:17.013  W     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
15:32:17.013  W     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
15:32:17.013  W     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
15:32:17.013  W     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
15:32:17.014  W     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
15:32:17.014  W     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
15:32:17.014  W     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
15:32:17.014  W     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
15:32:17.014  W     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
15:32:17.014  W     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
15:32:17.015  W  Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
15:32:17.015  W     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1605)
15:32:17.015  W     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
15:32:17.019  W     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
15:32:17.020  W     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
15:32:17.021  W     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:130)
15:32:17.021  W     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:62)
15:32:17.021  W     at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120)
15:32:17.021  W     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:935)
15:32:17.023  W     ... 23 more
```

Comment: Please [reconsider your use of JDBC on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android?r=Saves_AllUserSaves)

Comment: this is my requirement i have to fetch data from MySql db without any API call how can do that

Comment: Tell the person that gave you this "requirement" that what they are requiring is insecure, unstable, and a poor practice in mobile app development.